# SQLAlchemy self referencial table get the number of grandchilds

Tags: sqlalchemy

I got a User model and each user has another user as a parent. Now, to get the number of children (users that belong to a given model instance) I have defined this property:

```
class User( object ):

    @property
    def childsCount( self ):
        return object_session(self).scalar(
            select([func.count(User.users_id)]).where(User.parent_id==self.users_id)
        )
```

...which works ok. What I don't know is how do I get the count of grandchilds? Or even grandgrandchilds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [aliased](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) to composed the deeper level `WHERE` clauses. In fact you can do it somewhat more generic:

```
@property
def childrenCount(self):
    return self.count_children(0)

@property
def grandchildrenCount(self):
    return self.count_children(1)

@property
def grandgrandchildrenCount(self):
    return self.count_children(2)

def count_children(self, level=0):
    a = [aliased(User) for _ in range(level + 1)]
    qry = select([func.count(a[0].users_id)]).where(a[-1].parent_id==self.users_id)
    # insert all the intermediate JOINs
    for _i in range(level):
        qry = qry.where(a[_i].parent_id == a[_i+1].users_id)
    return Session.object_session(self).scalar(qry)
```

Although it looks somewhat cryptic, what it really does is expaned as below (add one `alias` and `where` clause for each deeper level):

```
@property
def children1Count(self):
    a0 = aliased(User)
    qry = select([func.count(a0.users_id)]).where(a0.parent_id==self.users_id)
    return Session.object_session(self).scalar(qry)

@property
def children2Count(self):
    a0 = aliased(User)
    a1 = aliased(User)
    qry = select([func.count(a0.users_id)]).where(a0.parent_id==a1.users_id).where(a1.parent_id==self.users_id)
    return Session.object_session(self).scalar(qry)

@property
def children3Count(self):
    a0 = aliased(User)
    a1 = aliased(User)
    a2 = aliased(User)
    qry = select([func.count(a0.users_id)]).where(a0.parent_id==a1.users_id).where(a1.parent_id==a2.users_id).where(a2.parent_id==self.users_id)
    return Session.object_session(self).scalar(qry)
```

---

For first level only you can actually have a nicer query with [with_parent](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_parent):

```
@property
def childrenCount(self):
    return Session.object_session(self).query(User).with_parent(self).count()
```

Comment: man i'm still new to sqlalchemy and python but this is chinese already. Will try to digest it. Btw, it works! Thanks.

Comment: @Romeo: `decrypted` somewhat the code for easier understanding